# IE Ignores Whitespace Chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I've got a textarea with a div behind (containing the same contents as the textarea, but with spans for highlighting) and it works fine in Chrome and Firefox (with some width hacking due to the border). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuNus/29/)

I just can't get it to work in IE (currently testing in 8). Seems to be somehow related to `whitespace` or `word-wrap` because you can see the div at the back ignoring whitespace after 2 chars.

`.replace(/[ \xA0]{2}/g, " &nbsp;")` seems to help make the div duplicate the textarea contents better, but still doesn't fix the problem and ends up breaking Chrome + FF.

*I posted a similar question last week, but have since made some progress and have isolated the problem to IE*

Thanks

Comment: `.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp')` seems to be doing the trick.. http://jsfiddle.net/nuNus/31/

Comment: @techfoobar breaks in Chrome

Comment: @techfoobar gives weird result in chrome/ie9

Comment: @techfoobar Yeah. Problems in IE + Chrome, as mplungjan says. Thank you though :) .. This really has me tearing my hair out!

Comment: Hmm.. Tried only in IE. IE really has a long way to go!

Comment: I've never seen a cross-browser solution of this implementation working properly. I believe that the likes of codemirror use a much more complex method which involves moving an input field around - but for a simple highlight I was hoping for a simple solution.